# Error with including loaders in webpack.config.js

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, ionic3, webpack.config.js

I am trying to integrate a third party angular component into an Ionic 3 demo application.

That angular component is having HTML, CSS & SCSS inside, so I've modified my webpack.config.js to include loaders.

This has created two problems for me:

1. "Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined"
2. Sass Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/mixins

[image]

**My webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ionicWebpackFactory = require(process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_FACTORY);

var ModuleConcatPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/ModuleConcatenationPlugin');
var PurifyPlugin = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer').PurifyPlugin;

var optimizedProdLoaders = [
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },

      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getProdLoaders() {
  if (process.env.IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS === 'true') {
    return optimizedProdLoaders;
  }
  return devConfig.module.loaders;
}

var devConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            options: {
              resources: 'node_modules/@plentymarkets/terra-components/app/assets/styles/_variables.scss'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};

var prodConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: getProdLoaders()
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin(),
    new ModuleConcatPlugin(),
    new PurifyPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};


module.exports = {
  dev: devConfig,
  prod: prodConfig
}
```

**Is there anything wrong with the loaders in my webpack.config.js?**

Please let me know if there is such.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How could we help you without seeing the config file?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put my code. Updated question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "issue Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined" is related with not using a compatible angular version, you might be using terra components with version 5 of angular. Downgrade angular version to 4 and check if the error still exists.

Another issue "Sass Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/mixins" is with sass-loader. sass-loader usually detects ~ and searches in the node modules for the same. In this case sass-loader is not recognizing it and it is throwing an error. Change ~ to node_modules and check if error is still present. For more info about this issue check https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

Comment: Thank you, I am able to fix them. According to your comments, I've downgraded my Angular version to 4 and replaced ~ with node_modules/. I am able to run the app successfully now.